# 'override_dh_auto_configure' failed because of unrecognized arguments/flags to gcc

Tags: debian, packaging, autotools, deb, dpkg

I am trying to cross-compile and build a Debian package

- build - `x86_64-linux-gnu` (Ubuntu 18.04)
- host - `i686-unknown-linux-gnu` (Debian 8, with `gcc` version 4.1.2)

Placed my SDK at `/opt/xtools`. `debuild` failed while performing `override_dh_auto_configure`

```
sudo debuild --prepend-path=/opt/urtool-3.0/bin -eLDFLAGS="-W"
```

This is what `config.log` looked like:

```
configure:3801: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3823: i686-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/ach/Downloads/gperftools/gperftools-2.6.90=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wformat=1,-Wno-format-extra-args -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -W conftest.c  >&5
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Werror=format-security"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wdate-time"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdebug-prefix-map=/home/ach/Downloads/gperftools/gperftools-2.6.90=."
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fstack-protector-strong"
configure:3827: $? = 1
configure:3865: result: no
configure: failed program was:
```

It failed because of unrecognized command line options to `gcc` (version gcc-4.1.2 being very old). How can I remove/ignore these unrecognized command line options while performing `debuild`?